# What are the ramifications of renaming Google Analytics 4 event names?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Is the renaming retrospective? i.e. are the historical events with the old event name retained in GA4 rather than destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872?hl=en

> Modified and created events do not apply to historical data.